# Fully Move Grub to New Partition

Tags: boot, grub2, 18.04

How do you fully move Grub to a new partition? When I installed Ubuntu (Kubuntu) I only allocated 256 MiB for the `/boot` partition which doesn't appear to be enough. Every time a new kernel is installed the install fails part way through due to there not being enough space so I have to manually intervene. So I'm trying to move grub from my old boot partition, `/dev/sdb5`, to my new 512 MiB partition, `/dev/sdb7`.

I edited `/etc/fstab` to point use the new boot partition.

```
# /boot was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
#UUID=f1fcbfbe-7943-4e48-9796-8d0c42076c0b      /boot   ext4    defaults        0       2
# /boot is now on /dev/sdb7
UUID=70d8be3a-6b6c-4722-ab0d-e79d93e6dd1c       /boot   ext4    defaults        0       2
```

I unmounted `/boot/efi` (`/dev/sdb2`), and `/boot` (`/dev/sdb5`). And then mounted `/dev/sdb7` as `/boot`, remounted `/boot/efi`, and remounted `/dev/sdb5` as `/mnt/boot`.

I ran:

```
$ sudo grub-install /dev/sdb7
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

And:

```
$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sdb2@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

However, the Linux image is missing from `/boot`:

```
$ ls -1 /boot
efi
grub
lost+found
```

While the old `/boot` has:

```
$ ls -1 /mnt/boot/
abi-4.15.0-32-generic
abi-4.15.0-33-generic
config-4.15.0-32-generic
config-4.15.0-33-generic
efi
grub
initrd.img-4.15.0-33-generic
lost+found
memtest86+.bin
memtest86+.elf
memtest86+_multiboot.bin
retpoline-4.15.0-32-generic
retpoline-4.15.0-33-generic
System.map-4.15.0-32-generic
System.map-4.15.0-33-generic
vmlinuz-4.15.0-33-generic
```

I must be missing a step. What is the proper process to do this? Is there a command I'm missing to rebuild the Linux image?

NOTE: The reason I want `/boot` to be a separate partition from `/` is because `/` is a LUKS encrypted ext4 partition.

---

Output from `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: CFE364AE-6B98-4A85-BE10-7E8A8833426F

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048 976762879 976760832 465.8G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda2  976762880 977287167    524288   256M Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 1AB601E6-CACA-4A3F-828A-A334CC3564DF

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1        2048     923647     921600   450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sdb2      923648    1128447     204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sdb3     1128448    1161215      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb4     1161216 1534093311 1532932096   731G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb5  1534093312 1534617599     524288   256M Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb6  1534617600 1952475135  417857536 199.3G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb7  1952475136 1953523711    1048576   512M Linux filesystem




Disk /dev/mapper/sdb6_crypt: 199.3 GiB, 213940961280 bytes, 417853440 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Output from `lsblk -lf`:

```
NAME       FSTYPE      LABEL          UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                        
sda1       ntfs        Extra Disk     54186D8E186D7042                     
sda2       ext4                       fae6b821-6644-4883-a2f1-da5c42485431 
sdb                                                                        
sdb1       ntfs        Recovery       44F21BC7F21BBC5C                     
sdb2       vfat                       941C-5A1E                            /boot/efi
sdb3                                                                       
sdb4       ntfs                       6C32289F3228706E                     
sdb5       ext4        Linux Boot Old f1fcbfbe-7943-4e48-9796-8d0c42076c0b /boot
sdb6       crypto_LUKS                b2d73541-783b-4336-a62c-1e11d0cc2b47 
sdb7       ext4        Linux Boot     70d8be3a-6b6c-4722-ab0d-e79d93e6dd1c 
sr0                                                                        
sdb6_crypt ext4        Linux Root     1e8b2b29-1857-4b38-84ee-d3c386f5085e /
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I could achieve it by doing it in the following way.

Below is the actual command lines view when I changed `/boot` partition from sda7 to sda9

```
kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda2: UUID="BCB3-3DA0" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="e5db3aba-af70-4112-8858-1aff620887a0"
/dev/sda3: UUID="F2B6E7A8B6E76C13" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="02c16852-6715-42db-ac16-c9007d86934a"
/dev/sda4: UUID="2d2846e3-4382-4dec-bad3-ec27c9f3311d" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="67dd28fb-4a80-4deb-aa25-8f1b93f1a4ba"
/dev/sda5: LABEL="SAS DI" UUID="605EEA015EE9D038" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="82da16ec-8c57-41b8-9f8b-e2d2bdc3b183"
/dev/sda6: LABEL="MADURI" UUID="C4F8CC63F8CC54F8" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="6c75ef1c-376c-4ede-9072-3a888b0bf94d"
/dev/sda7: UUID="4eab37c8-7d22-4580-b53e-47e8768318c8" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="8d49090a-7495-4f10-a83d-3e4f4abca525"
/dev/sda8: UUID="e569a993-a701-4b1f-acc1-ba0e862ba0de" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Kubuntu 18.04" PARTUUID="af772c38-570b-4e9b-a5ce-ca26b28bec1a"
/dev/sda9: UUID="360b1c4c-b6f8-49fd-93e2-c9c086e95e4c" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="3327a153-0c8a-46c1-a23d-ef4774564875"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="c2ca0fe9-67db-468a-bf0f-8d9ce78cf129"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="2018-07-25-03-28-48-00" LABEL="Kubuntu 18.04.1 LTS amd64" TYPE="iso9660" PTUUID="418c5dc0" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="418c5dc0-01"
/dev/sdb2: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="0D5F-1DB6" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="418c5dc0-02"
kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda8 /mnt
kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda9 /mnt/boot
kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ sudo chroot /mnt
root@kubuntu:/# sudo nano /etc/fstab
sudo: unable to resolve host kubuntu: Resource temporarily unavailable
root@kubuntu:/# exit
exit
kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ sudo mkdir /mnt/home/OBP
kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda7 /mnt/home/OBP
kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ sudo cp -r /mnt/home/OBP/* /mnt/boot/
kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot/efi
kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ for i in /sys /proc /dev /run; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt$i"; done
kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ sudo chroot /mnt                                                                                                                                                             
root@kubuntu:/# update-grub                                                                                                                                                                     
Generating grub configuration file ...                                                                                                                                                          
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-29-generic                                                                                                                                              
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic                                                                                                                                          
grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdb1.  Check your device.map.                                                                                                              
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda2@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi                                                                                                                        
Found Ubuntu 18.10 (18.10) on /dev/sda4                                                                                                                                                         
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration                                                                                                                                           
done                                                                                                                                                                                            
root@kubuntu:/# grub-install /dev/sda                                                                                                                                                           
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.                                                                                                                                                             
Installation finished. No error reported.                                                                                                                                                       
root@kubuntu:/# update-grub                                                                                                                                                                     
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic
grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdb1.  Check your device.map.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda2@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Found Ubuntu 18.10 (18.10) on /dev/sda4
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
root@kubuntu:/# ls -1 /boot
abi-4.15.0-29-generic
config-4.15.0-29-generic
efi
grub
initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic
lost+found
memtest86+.bin
memtest86+.elf
memtest86+_multiboot.bin
retpoline-4.15.0-29-generic
System.map-4.15.0-29-generic
vmlinuz-4.15.0-29-generic
root@kubuntu:/# lsblk -lf
NAME  FSTYPE   LABEL                     UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
loop0 squashfs                                                                
sda                                                                           
sda1                                                                          
sda2  vfat                               BCB3-3DA0                            /boot/efi
sda3  ntfs                               F2B6E7A8B6E76C13                     
sda4  ext4                               2d2846e3-4382-4dec-bad3-ec27c9f3311d 
sda5  ntfs     SAS DI                    605EEA015EE9D038                     
sda6  ntfs     MADURI                    C4F8CC63F8CC54F8                     
sda7  ext4                               4eab37c8-7d22-4580-b53e-47e8768318c8 /home/OBP
sda8  ext4                               e569a993-a701-4b1f-acc1-ba0e862ba0de /
sda9  ext4                               360b1c4c-b6f8-49fd-93e2-c9c086e95e4c /boot
sdb   iso9660  Kubuntu 18.04.1 LTS amd64 2018-07-25-03-28-48-00               
sdb1  iso9660  Kubuntu 18.04.1 LTS amd64 2018-07-25-03-28-48-00               
sdb2  vfat     Kubuntu 18.04.1 LTS amd64 0D5F-1DB6                            
sr0                                                                           
root@kubuntu:/# exit
exit
kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ shutdown now
```

Things to know before log on to "Try Kubuntu" session.

1. Root partition; in my case it is `/dev/sda8`.
2. EFI partition; in my case it is `/dev/sda2`.
3. `/boot` old partition; in my case it is `/dev/sda7`.
4. New `/boot` partition; in my case it is `/dev/sda9`.
5. Drive letter of the hard disk; in my case it is sda.

I am going to change my boot partition from sda7 to sda9

[image]

Log on with Kubuntu 18.04 "Try Kubuntu" session.

Open Konsole and run the command

1. `sudo blkid` and copy the UUID of the partition that is going to be new /boot partition that is sda9
2. `sudo mount /dev/sda8 /mnt` # mounting root partition
3. `sudo mount /dev/sda9 /mnt/boot` # mounting new /boot partition
4. `sudo chroot /mnt`
5. `nano /etc/fstab` # open the fstab file

Manually scroll down to the UUID part of `/boot` in the `/etc/fstab` file by arrow keys.

Paste the copied UUID (from step 1) by deleting the UUID of old boot partition.

To save the file, press 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>

6. `exit` # exit from chroot

Before mounting the `/boot/efi` partition we have to copy the data in old boot partition to new boot partition.

7. `sudo mkdir /mnt/home/OBP` # folder creation for mounting old boot partition
8. `sudo mount /dev/sda7 /mnt/home/OBP` # Old Boot Partition Mounting
9. `sudo cp -r /mnt/home/OBP/* /mnt/boot/`
10. `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot/efi`
11. `for i in /sys /proc /dev /run; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt$i"; done`
12. `sudo chroot /mnt`
13. `update-grub`
14. `grub-install /dev/sda`
15. `update-grub`
16. `exit`
17. `shutdown now`

Fresh start the system and you may now delete the old boot partition.

[image]

Comment: Although I've answered myself, I like the details and screenshots in your answer so +1.

Answer (score 3):

### 256 MB for `/boot` and 200 GB for `/`

You have lots of space but `/boot` directory is "space challenged". I'd suggest moving `/boot` from `sdb5` to `/` on `sdb6`.

Your current plan of moving `/boot` to new partition `sdb7` which is only 512 MB seems limited. Sometimes my `/boot` can be many GB if I'm testing out multiple kernels.

### How to move `/boot` to `/`

There is already an answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/385713/200094):

Yes it is possible. Also its not easy. If you intent to move separated /boot partition and or / partition you should consider first of all changing the fstab entries.

If you are moving the files to new partition then don't forget to use `cp -p` while copying to preserve permissions. adjust then your `/etc/fstab` to the new UUID's of partitions that you will use. YOu can get the partition uuid by running `blkid /dev/sdXn` where X is name of the drive and n number of partition.

You can also use blkid to attach labels to your partitions and then mount via labels which is much easier read `man blkid` to learn more.

After you change the partitions and adjust /etc/fstab you should run the `update-grub` - available on Debian/Ubuntu script or `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` to generate a new config file and then reinstall grub into the first hdd that you bot from. `grub-install --recheck /dev/sdb`

Of course do not forget that when copiying mount a new / or /boot partition on /mnt and after copying all of the files mount them as / and /boot chroot and only then run update of the grub if you want things to be done correctly.

Comment: I forgot to mention the reason `/boot` is a separate partition is because `/` is a LUKS encrypted ext4 partition. 512 MiB for `/boot` probably is too small. I'll bump it up to 1 GiB. I don't test new kernels other than when apt-get updates it, and I verify that I can boot successfully.

Comment: @cpburnz Understood. Still if I had to have a separate `/boot` partition I would err on the side of caution and go with say 1 or 2 GB which is only .5% or 1% of your 200 GB storage space. Remember if you forget to run `sudo apt autoremove` you might end up with a few kernels. Then I would have a cron reboot job that emailed me if I had more than 3 kernels installed. Thanks for explaining encryption  use as I've never traveled that road.

Answer (score 1):

So, I guess you need just move/copy all kernel files from old directory to new, and update grub. Try: `sudo cp /mnt/boot/* /boot && sudo update-grub`