# Resize /boot partition

Tags: partitioning, kubuntu, gparted

I want to resize my `/boot` partition.
I have gparted live CD and can do this pretty easily.

But the problem is my order of partitions:

[image: gparted]

I can shrink `sbd4` or `sdb5` to get some extra space.

In the end I can also extend `sdb1` (without moving the head of it).

But the question is:

> Can I **move** `sdb2` and `sdb3` so it does not corrupt my system?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, you can merge them and later separate them (if you want) does this mean 'moving' partitions in your sense? https://askubuntu.com/questions/3402/how-to-move-boot-and-root-partitions-to-another-drive

Comment: New versions of Ubuntu do  not normally need /boot partition nor swap partition as it uses a swap file. You do need the ESP - efi system partition for UEFI boot. And swap over 4GB is a waste unless you want to hibernate, which is not suggested.  I would just move /boot back into / and eliminate the /boot partition. You can comment out /boot in fstab and use boot repair to totally  reinstall grub & new kernel. Or copy all of /boot partition to /boot folder in / (root).

Comment: may this help?? https://askubuntu.com/q/1073470/739431

Comment: @oldfred, hibernation I actually use, so swap I would keep; but what about EFI? can I just remove it? shall I fix the system afterwards? and speaking of moving root to /, I like the idea, but a couple of guides I checked told me to copy and unmount /boot.. which is not possible to do as it is busy.. can this be done only with live cd?

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka, thank you for the reference, by moving I mentioned just changing the position on the hdd

Comment: If you delete ESP, you will not be able to boot. You copy boot partition files to /boot folder. Then edit fstab. When you reboot it will use the files in the folder, not in partition.

Comment: @oldfred, do I need to reinstall grub after moving or changing fstab is enough?

Comment: You may have to as its core.img looks for boot.

Comment: @oldfred, unfortunately, this will not work, as I want encryption on / partition. Can I still move via gparted? will it be harmful to move efi partition?

Comment: Normally encrypted is full drive with LVM - logical volumes. You did not show LVM as part of your system? And yes LVM usually uses a separate /boot partition.

Comment: @oldfred, no, I do not have LVM, just normal partitions. But root partition I still can encrypt. It is only boot must be separate. Still to the problem, do you think I can move efi and swap?

Comment: Moving file should not change UUID and normally is ok. Again good backups. I would consider deleting swap and moving it to end of drive. But then you have to edit fstab with new swap's UUID before rebooting. Maybe comment out old swap, so system will reboot. Then create new swap from live installer. Then you can boot & easily change fstab. Always after fstab edit: `sudo mount -a` I normally have ESP a first partition and used to have swap as last partition as those would not normally ever be changed. But now use swap file as newer Ubuntu uses swap file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case to get extended `/boot` I did the following:

1. Boot with GParted live CD
2. Cut 1 GB at the end of `sdb4`
3. Copy `sdb1` to this newly allocated space and fully resize this copy to 1 GB
4. Generate new UUID for `sdb1` so it does not collide with its copy (as UUID is also copied)
5. Apply all the changes

Done!

Pros:

- easy and fast operation

Cons:

- `sdb1` is now unused

Answer (score 1):

if you install a new kernel and it complains about no space on /boot, simply purge the old kernel. no need to resize /boot. to do that, install purge-old-kernels command

```
sudo apt-get install byobu
```

then run `sudo purge-old-kernels`, this is going to clean up the old kernels.

also, if you really want to resize, left-shrink your swap space by 500MB or 1GB, that's more than sufficient to accommodate your `/boot` folder. This has very little impact to your system performance (if your swap is over 8GB - in face, 14GB is quite generous).

Comment: thank you for advice, but speaking of moved partitions, can I actually move /boot/efi as it stands right after /boot